# widget form method in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I need your help.

I have this code

```
<?php 
class Messenger extends WP_Widget
{
  function Messenger()
  {
    $widget_ops = array('classname' => 'Messenger', 'description' => 'Displays messages for users' );
    $this->WP_Widget('Messenger', 'Messenger', $widget_ops);
  }

 public function form($instance)
  {
    extract($instance);

    ?>
    Title
        <input class="widefat"
               id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('title') ?>"
            name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('title')?>"                                    
            value="<?php  if(isset($title)) echo $title;  ?>"
        />
    <?php
  }

  public function update()
  {
  }

  public function widget()
  {
  }

}
add_action( 'widgets_init', function(){return register_widget("Messenger");});?>
```

but unfortunately this error occurred Warning: extract() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in C:\wamp\www\pt\wp-content\plugins\Messenger\Messenger.php on line 22
I do not know why, I do not know why the $instance keep null after I submit the form.

Comment: `extract`, what `extract`? Can you post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: sorry, I edited it. @brasofilo

Comment: Compare the letters with the link in my first comment ;)

Comment: Yes, but it is MVCE now because I edited it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59547/discussion-between-mohammad-and-brasofilo).